# Rebuild Sitecore Analytics Index without affecting the Sitecore Experience Platform

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, indexing

I am using `Sitecore 8.2` with `MongoDb` as a `Sitecore xDB`.

In our application, Sitecore `Custom Contact Facets` being used and data for these custom facets already present in `MongoDB`. Now I wanted to create a new user segmentation rule based on one of the fields and this field, not part of the Search indexing Sitecore Analytics Index (**Sitecore_analytics_index**) so in order to use the field in the custom segmentation rule, I have to add this field for indexing.

The Sitecore Analytics indexing (**Sitecore_analytics_index**) is different from Sitecore Content Indexing ( e.g., **Sitecore_web_index**) so we can't rebuild the Sitecore Analytics Index and it can be only populated during aggregation process, means if any update would happen in the Sitecore Contacts in `MongoDB`.

In this case, I can't use the custom rule (created on the field which added for indexing) for the old Sitecore Contacts (approximately 1 million).

Also, I can't use **SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex** because it's not supported for Sitecore Analytics Index(Sitecore_analytics_index), in this case, if I will try to `rebuild` then the user will experience the issue on Sitecore `Experience Platform`, and I assume that it will reset all the data first then start adding again.

I also checked the tool at  https://vohil.net/2017/05/16/rebuild-sitecore-analytics-index-without-re-building-reporting-database/ but it's not working properly due to a large number of Sitecore Contacts.

Is there any way to `rebuild` the **Sitecore Analytics Index** which has `large numbers` of Sitecore Contacts without affecting the Sitecore Experience Platform (e.g. use of `Sitecore Contacts`, `segmentation`..)?

Comment: Just an FYI that on Sitecore 9.x+ this data is kept in the xDB index which does allow for switching. Might be a reason for the client to think about an upgrade.

Comment: @ChrisAuer Thanks for the response. Upgrade is already planned but till its upgraded need to support existing system requirements.